# What is the n parameter of tkinter.mainloop function?

Tags: python, tkinter

A `n` parameter may be given to `tkinter.mainloop` function,

```
help(tkinter.Tk.mainloop)
>>>> mainloop(self, n=0) # What is n here ?
     Call the mainloop of Tk.
```

I was not able to find any documentation about it

What is the purpose of this `n` parameter?

Comment: Where did you find reference to the `n` parameter?  I can't find it in any documentation or usage examples.

Comment: @Prune, `help(tkinter.Tk.mainloop)` describes the function as `mainloop(self, n=0)`

Comment: Darn ... no leads from there.  I've also bottomed out on trying to find a reference.  Just saw @Novel's comment; I was suspicious of `DoOneEvent`, but couldn't find a distinct reference to link that back to a `Mainloop` parameter.

Comment: @Prune This has not to do with `DoOneEvent`. See my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you can see in the **C implementation** of Tkinter , [`_tkinter_tkapp_mainloop_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/77473846439b8a3eae66de1a1cfe931619f38513/Modules/_tkinter.c#L2699),

```
_tkinter_tkapp_mainloop_impl(TkappObject *self, int threshold)
```

`n` represent the `threshold` parameter passed to the function.

Now, looking at the implementation itself, it is possible to see this loop at the beginning of the function,

```
 while (Tk_GetNumMainWindows() > threshold &&
       !quitMainLoop &&
       !errorInCmd)
```

Hence, you can see that the code is meant to drop out of the `mainloop` when the number of *root level* windows drops to `threshold` or below.

Note that by default the optional parameter will have a value of `0` which logically means it will stay active if ***any***  *root level* windows are opened.

**Further information**

I can't comment on why this `threshold` parameter was added, but the lack of documentation and/or information on this specific parameter most likely comes from the fact that it seems quite rare that someone would pass `n` explicitly to `tkinter.mainloop` and change the default behavior.

Comment: This answer is very slightly misleading because of your choice of terminology. It's not the number of _top-level_ windows (ie: instances of `Toplevel` are not considered). It's the number of root windows -- those created by instantiating `Tk`. You can see this by observing the difference in a program where you create one root and multiple toplevels vs. multiple roots.

Comment: @BryanOakley I actually just confirmed that and you seem right. I edited. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Digging through the history of the file, it was [added Nov 10, 1994](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f34cadda28d6ac41942dd87acc3cc4821506a052). The commit message isn't very enlightening: _"added timer and file callbacks and global mainloop and quit fns"_.  (first commit of that file was June 1994).