# Integer Parameter in mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

I wanted to know about the optional integer parameter for the `mainloop()` function.
There is no documentation about this on python.org nor youtube.

---

**The First Code**: passing no parameters in mainloop

```
from tkinter import *

def fun():
    global i
    print("hello", i)
    i += 1
    root.mainloop()
    print("Hi", i)
    return

i = 0
root = Tk()
button1 = Button(root, text="click", command=fun)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()

print("end")
```

**Output:** clicked button 3 times and closed window

```
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
Hi 3
Hi 3
Hi 3
end
```

---

**The Second code**: passing i in mainloop

```
from tkinter import *

def fun():
    global i
    print("hello", i)
    i += 1
    root.mainloop(i)
    print("Hi", i)
    return

i = 0
root = Tk()
button1 = Button(root, text="click", command=fun)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop(i)

print("end")
```

**Output**: clicked button 3 times and closed window

```
hello 0
Hi 1
hello 1
Hi 2
hello 2
Hi 3
end
```

---

the codes without parameters are working in a suspicious manner which I believe is could be due to recursion.

Comment: Unless you have a deep understanding of how tk works at the C level, you  should ignore this parameter. However, you can see precisely how its used by looking at the c code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c

Comment: Understanding tkinter mainloop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the n parameter of tkinter.mainloop function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386979/what-is-the-n-parameter-of-tkinter-mainloop-function)